# how to convert materialized view into normal view

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I am using Oracle 11g EE and created one Materialized view for a complex query.
But as customer is using Standard edition and it doesn't support Materialized view.
So I need to convert materialized view into a normal view.
Along with this conversion I also need to make sure performance of a query.
When I treid to execute a query for the view independently, it takes around 20 mins which is too much time.
All my tables are indexed.

Any sort of help would be appreciated !!

Comment: when was the last time you performed run stats on the indexed entities?

Comment: NIght job inserts records into the MV on daily basis. Today is the last stat performed on this table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't currently have access to an oracle database to test this, but if you get the DDL of the mview, and remove the word `materialized` along with the mview related options:

`select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('MATERIALIZED_VIEW', 'MVIEW_NAME') from dual;`

You should be able to create a normal view from the resulting modified statement.

As for performance, make sure you are indexing the right things, and using the right type of indexes. Make sure statistics are up to date, and finally run `explain plan` on the view query. The topic of interpreting and optimizing execution plans is deep - start here:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm